# Find non numeric data for a column between duplicate key records

Tags: duplicates, numbers, alphanumeric

I have a table (student_table) with 5 columns in which alphanumeric data was stored earlier in one of the column.The combination was unique. However, due to a change at source, the aplhanumeric values were replaced with numeric values and inserted, keeping rest of the column values same which was still unique.  Refer sample data below -

| Student Id | Student Name | Class | Section | Subject |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | Secondary | A | Maths |
| 1 | ABC | Secondary | A | 1 |
| 2 | XYZ | Secondary | A | English |
| 2 | XYZ | Secondary | A | 2 |
| 3 | TES | Secondary | A | 2 |

I used the below query but that only give me the records of students having more than one subject.

Select Student_id, Student_name, Class, Section
from (Select DISTINCT Student_id, Student_name, Class, Section
from student_table
where Student_id  = 1)
having count(subject) > 1
group by Student_id, Student_name, Class, Section;

I want to delete the 2 records where the subject is alphanumeric/string i.e. 'Maths','English' and keep only the 3 rows with numeric values in Subject column. How can I do that? There is no foreign key relationship between this table as there is no master table for subject codes.